# Spring MVC accessing command object in Popup

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, popup, command

I have a spring MVC command form that displays a table from an arraylist of objects and there is a hyper link on a column that opens up a popup.
The user performs a selection on this popup and clicks a button to save his choice. I have two questions:

1. What are the best ways of opening the popup?
2. How do I set the command object values from the user selections in the opened popup ?

Any inputs or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer question 1 you could use jQuery UI to open a popup dialog. Example: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
For question 2 that could also be done using jquery.